# Вертикальный slick slider в обратном направлении (первый слайд внизу)

Tags: javascript, html, html5, slick.js, slider-slick.js

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в вертикальном `slick slider` закрепить первый слайд внизу, а не наверху?

```
$slider.slick({
    slidesToShow: 5,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    swipe: true,
    verticalSwiping: true,
    variableWidth: false,
    dots: false,
    infinite: false,
    vertical: true,
    rtl: false
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `rtl: true` ? ||||||

Comment: это направление прокрутки

Answer (score 0):

покопатся в настройках возможно есть 50%50% ? если навернека и лень взять сам Dom элемент и просто перевернуть

```js
let ts = document.querySelector('.test')
ts.append(...Array.from(ts.children).reverse())
```

```html
    <div class="test">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    </div>
```